# Is it possible to make simple calculus on Kibana/Lucene queries?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following query on Kibana

```
temp:[0 TO 7] AND station_id:3
```

and I would like to have something like

```
(temp:[0 TO 7])/4 AND station_id:3
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Queries in Kibana follow the [Lucene query syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html) and are a way to describe which documents you want to retrieve.

Such processing would require scripts or post processing of the results which are not currently features of any Kibana panel.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do it on ES, getting the `value_count`divided by four?

Comment: Yes, you can achieve that with script fields: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html#search-request-script-fields

Comment: Probably, I was not clear. I need to get the result of the `value_count` aggregation divided by four